# DNS not resolving for root domain, only for subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, a-record

The domain I'm having issues with is `rossmasters.com`. Here's what happens when I attempt to resolve the root domain and a subdomain:

```
C:\Users\Ross>nslookup rossmasters.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Name:    rossmasters.com

C:\Users\Ross>nslookup www.rossmasters.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.0.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.rossmasters.com
Address:  178.79.185.207
```

My DNS rules are:

```
* A 178.79.185.207
www A 178.79.185.207
```

I'm not especially experienced with this but I use identical rules on another domain and they work fine. I can also nslookup another domain (not set as a DNS rule) and get the same result as `www`.

Is there anything I need to add in order to get `rossmasters.com` to resolve to the same IP or is this an issue with my registrar (who handle DNS records for both domains)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
@ A 178.79.185.207
```

Your `*` covers every subdomain of the root, but not the root itself.

What's your DNS server, by the way?  If it was bind, you'd need an `IN` in there..

Comment: So @ handles requests to the root part? I don't actually host my own DNS, it's hosted by my domain registrar (although I'm now considering it so I can learn more about this).

Comment: @ is an alias for the zone. Your zone is the top level of your domain so when you put @ it reference the rossmasters.com zone.